# Google Maps "place" vs "address"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

This is a followup question to another I recently had about the Google Maps API.

The following request returns zero results...

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=801+BALTIMORE+STREET%2c+Hanover%2c+PA%2c+17331&sensor=false

However, from http://maps.google.com the following address locates correctly...

```
801 Baltimore Street, Hanover, PA
```

From the previous question the answer was because the result returned from maps is a "place" and not an "address".

My new question is how can you tell maps is returning a "place" vs and "address"?  Is there something in the URL or the response that gives this away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the response on [Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=801+Baltimore+Street,+Hanover,+PA&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&hq=801+Baltimore+Street,+Hanover,+PA&radius=15000&t=m&z=13), notice the "3 reviews", that is a places entry.  The way the entry reads also indicates it to me:

```
Giant
801 Baltimore St, Hanover, PA ‎
(717) 632-6673 ‎ · giantfoodstores.com
3 reviews
```

It seems that the link above doesn't work the first time, but if you click on the "search" it finds it.

Comment: thanks, this tells us an explanation, but still we don't have a way to fix this. also the explanation is still kind of unfortunate: basically  my understanding is that googlemaps web actually uses 2 underlying services to present you results: address search (geocoding) and search  inside items of "places", where it possibly does a simply textual match on the address.  but if u just change the street number slightly, google maps web is still able to give you interpolated address along the same street, so it sort of implies it's using some geocoding correctly, so why not API?

Comment: pasting my duplicate question link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27052088/google-geocoding-api-cant-find-this-but-maps-console-can-find-it

Answer (score 0):

geocodezip:

thanks for the response.

assuming that the google maps web utilizes the places API, I tried to get the same result from places API.

for this address:  526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,Oahu,HI+96734
google maps does find the correct location. but geocoding API fails, so
I try the places API:

curl -v 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,Oahu,HI+96734&key=MY_API_KEY'

it returns a empty list. so why does the maps web page finds it but neither places API nor geocoding API finds it?

Thanks
Yang

Comment: Have you found a solution, I have the same problem with Université d'Ottawa, Ottawa, ON, Canada