# google maps web finds an address/place, but neither places API nor geocoding API finds it

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

(a repost of the answer at [Google Maps "place" vs "address"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18104208/google-maps-place-vs-address/27068152#27068152) )

assuming that the google maps web utilizes the places API, I tried to get the same result from places API.

for this address: 526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,Oahu,HI+96734 google maps does find the correct location. but geocoding API fails, so I try the places API:

curl -v 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query=526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,Oahu,HI+96734&key=MY_API_KEY'

it returns a empty list. so why does the maps web page finds it but neither places API nor geocoding API finds it?

Thanks Yang

Comment: Interesting.  I can only find that location in the places database when [I add the "Kailua Beach Park" to the address](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=Kailua%20Beach%20Park,+526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,Oahu,HI+96734&place=1)

Comment: If I take the formatted address from the Places entry "526 Kawailoa Rd, Kailua, HI 96734, United States" and geocode that, [I get a result (with "location_type": "RANGE_INTERPOLATED", so in a different place)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=526%20Kawailoa%20Rd,%20Kailua,%20HI%2096734,%20United%20States&geocode=1)

Comment: thanks a lot geocodezip!

Answer (score 1):

The "Oahu" is confusing the geocoder (and the places API).

If I use "526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,HI+96734" with the geocoder, [I get a result](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,HI+96734&geocode=1)

If I use that address with the places API, [I also get a result](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=526+Kawailoa+Road,Kailua,HI+96734&place=1)